# domain name validation with custom rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working on regular expression with own custom rule.

rules are the hostname must be 3-63 characters, 
whole name must be 256 characters,
no special characters except dot(.), hyphen(-)

I tried this `var regx = /^([A-Za-z0-9-]{3,63}?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;`

but the problem is the pattern is applicable to next string after dot(.). What I mean to say is

for example : "qwerty.abcde.com"

in the above "qwerty" should be 3-63 characters , but "abcde" can be any no.of characters .My pattern is applicable to next string after dot.that 3-63 rule should be applicable to  only "qwerty" not to  "abcde". can any one help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Must be 256 or up to 256? I think you mean *up to*. Try [`^(?![A-Za-z0-9.-]{257})([A-Za-z0-9-]{3,63})\.((?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*)([a-zA-Z]{2,6})$`](https://regex101.com/r/OhjTSJ/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for correcting me . upto 0-256 characters

Comment: Then try my regex, but  I think it is what you need. You may even replace `(?![A-Za-z0-9.-]{257})` with `(?!.{257})` to make it shorter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks you saved my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
/^(?!.{257})[A-Za-z0-9-]{3,63}\.(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OhjTSJ/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.{257})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the string contains 257 or more chars (other than line break chars)
- `[A-Za-z0-9-]{3,63}` - 3 to 63 alphanumeric and `-` chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric and `-` chars
  - `\.` - a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,6}` - 2 to 6 ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

So, the negative lookahead checks for the whole string length, and the `{3,63}` limiting quantifier is only applied to the chunk of chars before the first `.`.